# For certain Idp only Acs URL sends the 500 error and unfortunately nothing is logged or returned so as to understand what exactly is happening

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I am using **Sustainsys.Saml2** library in Asp net core 2

Whenver my client hits the request throught their IDP(let it be SP initiated or Idp initiated) it gives them 500 error.

We are clue less what exactly failing.

Is there any way by which we can log /see the exception thrown at our ACS URL `https://localhost:5000/KM/Acs`

Client's Idp is not accessible outside their corporate network.

On the other hand we tested same code with 3 different Idp and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The Sustainsys.Saml2 library logs errors to the Asp.Net Core logging framework, check those logs.